# iPhone View Cutting Off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

The view is created in interface builder, and is strangely cutting off at the bottom, and help or suggestions, is appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   


    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Edit: I don't actually have a nib for the view controller, but instead a main window nib and a nib for two different views which are different themes.

Also if I use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

it does not happen, but sadly this will crash in iOS 3.2 or below.

Comment: I have the status bar on in interface builder

Comment: May I see a screenshot of your simulated status bar settings?

Comment: And do you have the status bar enabled in all your other views, *including `MainWindow.xib`*?  Also, make sure in your target settings that you have the status bar enabled. http://i.imgur.com/05Xhp.jpg

Comment: Also seeing your edit, if you're adding your view controller without a XIB it probably isn't taking into account that you have the status bar enabled.

Comment: I just double check it is check for all that you mentioned

Comment: Is there a manual code way to do this?  If I use self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; this does not happen really strange.

Comment: You could always try this: `self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;`

Comment: that did not make a difference

Comment: Well I'm at a loss.  Without seeing it myself I couldn't help you further. :)  A last-ditch effort you could try is to set the view to the screen frame.  Like this: `viewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`

Comment: Yeah this problem has bothered me too, thanks for all your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experience the same problem, what I do is translating view 20 pixels down in ViewDidLoad then everything works fine. The problem surely is related to the statur bar but I do not know a solution other than this workaround.

To translate the view use this:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0, 20 );
```

Comment: That's awful... I mean, great that it works, but there is a reason that it is off and it should really be found.

Comment: @Vikings:  This might fix the problem temporarily, but just shifting your view down shouldn't be the good way to fix this.

Comment: I understand, i'm still looking for what's causing this

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder you need to check the dimensions of the view. You will see that it is too short (your height is probably set to 440, but it should be 460, or 480 if you don't have the status bar). This is probably why it appears to be cutting off.

Comment: Can you start a brand new project and see if it happens again?

Comment: self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController // this works but crashes in iOS 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling a simulated status bar in IB.

[image]